Multi-level rolling average with missing values
I have data on frequencies (N), for combinations of [from, to, subset], and the month. Importantly, when N=0, the row is missing.
                   N      from      to      subset
month                                             
1996-01-01  8.956799         1       2           0
1996-02-01  2.068997         1       2           0
1996-03-01  1.086952         1       2           0
1996-05-01  7.103955         1       2           0
1996-01-01         4         1       2           1
1996-03-01         5         1       2           1
1996-04-01         5         1       2           1
1996-05-01         6         1       2           1

I want to compute a rolling average of N over these, considering the zeros.
df.groupby(['from', 'to', 'subset.rolling(3, center=True).mean()

This works, but does not treat missing rows as zeros. So, I first have to fill the misisng rows.
df.reset_index().set_index(['month', 'from', 'to', 'subset']).resample('1M', level=0).fillna(0)

This does not work, and gives me ValueError: Upsampling from level= or on= selection is not supported, use .set_index(...) to explicitly set index to datetime-like.
Can I not upsample for a multi-index? Should I try a different approach altogether?
I would want this to work for any number of groups. My expected output for data above would be missings at the boundary (where the 3M centered rolling average cannot be computed), and a rolling average including zeros for the rest:
                  N                 from      to      subset
month                                             
1996-01-01    np.nan                   1       2           0
1996-02-01    [avg Jan-March]          1       2           0
1996-03-01    [avg Feb-April, April=0] 1       2           0
1996-04-01    [avg March-May, May=0]   1       2           0
1996-05-01    np.nan                   1       2           0
1996-01-01    np.nan                   1       2           1
1996-03-01    [avg Feb-April, Feb=0]   1       2           1
1996-04-01    [avg March-June Feb=0]   1       2           1
1996-05-01    np.nan                   1       2           1


Updated the sample data to be more explicit about non-unique index.

updated answer
resample.fillna is not supported with a MultiIndex (and would anyway only support ffill/bfill/nearest not a scalar). You could however perform a resampling/rolling per group with groupby.apply:
group = ['subset', 'from', 'to']
num_cols = ['N']

(df.groupby(group)
   .apply(lambda x: x[num_cols]
                    .resample('MS').mean().fillna(0)
                    .rolling(3, center=True).mean()
         )
   .reset_index(group)
   .reindex(columns=list(df)) # optional
)

Output:
                   N  from  to  subset
month                                 
1996-01-01       NaN     1   2       0
1996-02-01  4.037583     1   2       0
1996-03-01  1.051983     1   2       0
1996-04-01  2.730302     1   2       0
1996-05-01       NaN     1   2       0
1996-01-01       NaN     1   2       1
1996-02-01  3.000000     1   2       1
1996-03-01  3.333333     1   2       1
1996-04-01  5.333333     1   2       1
1996-05-01       NaN     1   2       1

original answer
resample.fillna is not supported with a MultiIndex (and would anyway only support ffill/bfill/nearest not a scalar), what you could do since you have unique dates initially would be to use a dummy resample.mean and then a classical fillna:
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

out = (df.set_index(['from', 'to', 'subset'], append=True)
         .resample('MS', level=0).mean().fillna(0)
         .rolling(3, center=True).mean()
      )

Which could be simplified to:
out = (df[['N']].resample('MS').mean().fillna(0)
       .rolling(3, center=True).mean()
      )

Output:
                   N
month               
1996-01-01       NaN
1996-02-01  4.037583
1996-03-01  1.051983
1996-04-01  2.730302
1996-05-01       NaN

If you want to keep the other columns:
tmp = df[['N']].resample('MS').mean().fillna(0).rolling(3, center=True).mean()

out = tmp.combine_first(df.drop(columns='N').reindex(tmp.index).ffill())

Output:
                   N  from  subset   to
month                                  
1996-01-01       NaN   1.0     0.0  2.0
1996-02-01  4.037583   1.0     0.0  2.0
1996-03-01  1.051983   1.0     0.0  2.0
1996-04-01  2.730302   1.0     0.0  2.0
1996-05-01       NaN   1.0     0.0  2.0


Would this answer work if there are multiple from/subset combinations for the same date? I'm getting ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels when attempting df.drop(columns='N').reindex(tmp.index).ffill()

As hinted in my answer ("since you have unique dates") not directly, but if you have several groups you could use a groupby.resample. Since your question did not have such groups, it might be worth opening a follow-up question with the updated logic (and example).

Oh, I wish I could undo the upvote then -- this is literally posting what I had in the question, stating it didnt work, since, as I was explicit in the question, I want this to work for multiple groups.

That's not how I interpreted the question and it was not explicit to me (you mentioned a MultiIndex, not groups), but I get your point. Do you mean that from/to could be variable? Can you make this explicit in the question?

There is a unique datetime index for each from-to-subset combination, any of those three variables could be .. variable :)

@FooBar I hope the update is what you're looking for
